# Find the first occurrence of each value in a column by groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe as follows:

```r
set.seed(456)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 5), x = sample(1:3, 10, TRUE))

   ID x
1   a 1
2   a 1
3   a 3
4   a 2
5   a 1
6   b 3
7   b 1
8   b 2
9   b 3
10  b 2
```

I want to create a new column `y` that displays the values of `x` if those values occur at the first time, otherwise `NA`. The operation should be done by `ID`. The expected output is

```
   ID x  y
1   a 1  1
2   a 1 NA
3   a 3  3
4   a 2  2
5   a 1 NA
6   b 3  3
7   b 1  1
8   b 2  2
9   b 3 NA
10  b 2 NA
```

Comment: `library(dplyr #>= 1.1.0 df %>% 
  mutate(y = if_else(duplicated(x), NA_real_, x), .by = ID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly more adventurous option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(x_unique = x*(!duplicated(x))^NA)

   ID        x x_unique
   <chr> <int>    <dbl>
 1 a         1        1
 2 a         1       NA
 3 a         3        3
 4 a         2        2
 5 a         1       NA
 6 b         3        3
 7 b         1        1
 8 b         2        2
 9 b         3       NA
10 b         2       NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace each row that is not the first for each ID and x, like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(y = replace(x, row_number() != 1, NA), .by = c(ID, x))
#>    ID x  y
#> 1   a 1  1
#> 2   a 1 NA
#> 3   a 3  3
#> 4   a 2  2
#> 5   a 1 NA
#> 6   b 3  3
#> 7   b 1  1
#> 8   b 2  2
#> 9   b 3 NA
#> 10  b 2 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>